# Linkedin REST API Requires Viewer to Have Linkedin Account?

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

Just to verify, noone can view anything on Linkedin without having an account on Linkedin?

I was planning on hosting all my professional articles on Linkedin but if I can't fetch them via the REST api to display them on my own website, I find that a non-starter.

Thanks in advance for clarification.

Comment: Why the downvote? I spent a couple of hours fighting w/ their REST api only to step back and realize that all connections to linkedin's REST api had to come from a linkedin user. (unless I am wrong - which is why I asked for clarification here).

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think you've just got things a bit backward. People don't usually make a website in order to drive traffic to their LinkedIn. If you've got a website, why are you not hosting your articles/blog on your site, and then posting those articles on LinkedIn?

However, in general, if you wanted your website to grab your LinkedIn info, it would have nothing to do with your viewer. You would essentially be logging your app/site behind the scenes (essentially as you), grabbing whatever fields are available that you want to display, and then popping them on the screen as static content.

Comment: My site does social media aggregation, for example, my tweets are displayed. I would like to show an 'articles' page but get/fetch the content from linkedin (my linkedin). My site is largely serverless (Firebase hosted) so all logic happens in the browser. Does that make sense?